# Date time null value skipped from Bulk API using OpenSerch.Net

Tags: opensearch

OpenSearch.Net 1 v1.2.0
.Net 4.7

We are using Bulk API to update multiple documents at the same time.

We have following Schema in.Net. I have removed some non required fields for simplicity. we are using Newtonsoft.Json for JsonProperty Attribute

```cs
 [OpenSearchType(IdProperty = "id", RelationName = "instant_offer")]
 public class InstantOfferDetailDto
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Nullable Instant offer id because it can be null when clone and assign offer
     /// </summary>
     [Number(Name = "id")]
     public long? Id { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
     [Object(Name = "offer")]
     public OfferDetailDto Offer { get; set; }
}

 public class OfferDetailDto
 {
      [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
      [Date(Name = "assign_date")]
      public DateTime? AssignDate { get; set; }
}
```

We are using .Net 4.7.

**OpenSearch Connection:**

```cs
 var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
                .PrettyJson()
                .DisableDirectStreaming()
                .RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)).DefaultIndex(indexName);
```

**Index Schema:**

```json
{
  "instant_offer": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "offer": {
          "properties": {
            "assign_date": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We want to update AssignDate to null in OpenSerach Document. so we are calling BulkAPI with AssignDate=null

We checked that Null Values are passed to Bulk API request, but it seems API does not update value to null and keep as it is. I checked DebugInformation and that assign_date did not exist in that request.

I think there should be some issue with OpenSearch Serialization.
Let me know how can I set null value to Datetime property?

We are calling Bulk API with Null values. but it seems null values are not set in document. instead values are kept as it is.